# Floating another div next to a main centered div

Tags: css, html, css-float, center

Ok so I have a website and the entire thing is wrapped in a container. This container is centered with margin:auto.  I would like to float a piece of content to the right of this centered container and have it sort of stick to the side of it no matter if the user resizes the browser window, etc. I'm wondering if there's a real simple way to do this rather than adding another huge div, giving it width and floating the centered portion to the left and the piece of content to the right. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Piggybacking on @NickAllen, you want to use absolute positioning so that the width of the sidebar isn't included in the centering on the primary container.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  right: -200px;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    [ sidebar content ]<br>
    [ sidebar content ]<br>
  </div>
  [content]<br>
  [content]<br>
  [content]<br>
</div>
```

Comment: ... with a caveat that because the sidebar is taken out of the layout calculations that you'll always want your primary content to be longer than the sidebar!

Comment: very weird that we both went for a 200px sidebar in our examples! lol

Comment: 200px leaves plenty of padding for those 160 x 600 banner ads... =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but isn't this what you want:

```css
    #container {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    
    #sidebar {
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="sidebar">
        some content
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the container div the property position: relative; place your floating div as the first child of the container div and give it

```
#floatingDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -{widthOfFloatedDiv};
}
```

I think that will work, but untested

Okay so tested it and it works

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #000; height: 400px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: -200px; width: 200px;">
        <p>Floated DIV</p>
    </div>
    <p>container div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but contributing since other answers were kinda lacking that "something" and it's still on top of Google. The simplest, cleanest way to achieve this is with *two wrappers*.

```
<div class="bigWrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">Hello, I'm your sidebar</div>      

  <div class="smallWrapper">
    Put the thing you want to center here.
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following css:

```
.bigWrapper { 
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.smallWrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Floating is the way to go for this. They will always stick together, unless the container is smaller than the sum of their widths.

Tip: make sure your container is wide enough to hold both inner divs; if not, and the user has a narrower window, they will show one below the other.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it will push the container div off center

Comment: It will not, if you set margins accordingly.