# Newbie CSS/HTML: How to add ad in a div container to the side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I got a centered website with a fixed width. Now, I want to add an ad banner of fixed width/height to the right side of the page. 
There is a wrapper div of width 700px. But I can't get my banner on the side. I dont know why. Can someone help me please with my CSS id?

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="head"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</div> //wrapper
```

EDIT:
<s>Image</s> - (link removed as broken)

This is what I want. I got the orange one. I don't want to set the banner position to the right browser border. It should be near the wrapper class.

Comment: Do you have any CSS in there, currently? If not then it will simply put the divs under each other since they are block elements.

Could you edit your post to show the code you are trying with the ad banner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the banner to be inside the wrapper:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="banner"></div>
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.banner { float: right; width: 100px; height: 400px; }
```

If you want it outside the wrapper:

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.banner { float: right; width: 100px; height: 400px; }
```

You can also check out this site for a bunch of different CSS/HTML layouts:

http://layouts.ironmyers.com/

*Following Edit...*

I think this question at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840542/floating-another-div-next-to-a-main-centered-div) has what you want.

Comment: The problem is, i want to center the main part of the page / 2. And with this solution (in wrapper) i get the center of the page (mainpart+ad)/2. 
http://yfrog.com/6lcsserrorg

The center is not longer in the middle of all, u know? 


If i put the banner outside the wrapper, it floats to the right side of the screen but not near the main content...

Comment: So you want the page centered in the middle and the ad container adjacent to it? Let me know if that's what you want. I haven't done something like that before, so I'll have to prototype it before I get you a solution.

Comment: I think I may have found another question that solved this problem. Check my original solution. Please let me know if this is not what you want and I'll play around with it when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this site and you will find the answer to your question and all the your future questions (judging by your question)
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

put the give the ad-div in the wrapper-div, give it an absolute position and move it to the right. Make sure to give the wrapper-div a relative position.

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="ad">ad</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper{
position: relative;
}

#ad {
position: absolute;
right: -140px;
}
```

The wrapper div will still be centered, the ad-div will 'hang' next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using float: right property ?

Comment: The problem is that "float: right" put the banner near the scrollbar, but i want it this way:
http://yfrog.com/6lcsseg