# Center an image and float another one to the right

Tags: css

I would like to have one div with two images. One is centered on the page and the other is all the way to the right.

I tried adding 'align: center' to the div, this centers the image fine. now when i add the other image and apply this:  'float:right'  the second image moves slightly to the right. So right now its being centered between the image and the left side of the page and not the whole page.

```
<div class="navigator" id="basket_status2" align="center">

<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<img src="images/icon/check-out_empty.png" border="0" alt=""></a>


<span style="float: right; ><a href="javascript:history.back();">
<img src="images/back_button.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></span>

</div>
```

Comment: OK I added some code, thanks

Comment: A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be more helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating another div next to a main centered div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840542/floating-another-div-next-to-a-main-centered-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to deal with floats. Just position the buttons to your liking:

```
.navigator {
    width            : 100%;
    height           : 20px;
    background-color : yellow;
    position         : relative;
}

.checkout {
    margin   : auto;
    height   : 20px;
    width    : 20px;
    border   : 1px solid green;
    position : relative;
    display  : block;
}

.back_button {
    height   : 20px;
    width    : 20px;
    border   : 1px solid red;
    position : absolute;
    right    : 0;
    top      : 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NJsvM/

Comment: It is slightly to the right. Make the width of the navigator 100% and update. You will see that its a bit to the right. The reason is because the image starts at the center and spans to the right, so its not centered itself.

Comment: Did you save. It still looks the same. Thanks.

Comment: Had to do some minor adjustments like remove top:0, and change the height of the navigator, but that did your css works. Thanks a lot.